# Getting result of exec*() from child process without waiting in any case (not using pipes and vfork())

Tags: c, linux, fork, waitpid, execv

I am working on custom wrappers for Unix-specific system calls now. And the last problem I met is about how to create a complete function for creating new processes with another image. And I want this function to return TRUE or FALSE. The last piece of this puzzle is how to get a result of `exec*()` from a child process without waiting for it's end in case of `exec*()`'s success. In other words, I need to get FAIL of SUCCESS result of exec*() quickly and continue execution of a parent process.

And I don't want to use `vfork()` and pipes.

My current results:

Using `vfork()` and a volatile variable for keeping result made their work.

```
static int QCreateProcess(char* args, ...)
{
    if (processInfoStruct == NULL)
    {
        return Q_ERROR;
    }
    
    volatile int result = TRUE;
    
    pid_t procHandle = vfork();
    if (procHandle == 0)
    {
        char* argsToExec[2] = { args, NULL };
        execv(argsToExec[0], argsToExec);
    
        result = FALSE;
        _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if (procHandle == -1)
    {
        processInfoStruct->processHandle = NULL;
        result = FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        if (result == TRUE)
        {
            waitpid(procHandle, NULL, WNOHANG);
            processInfoStruct->processHandle = procHandle;
        }
        else
        {
            processInfoStruct->processHandle = 0;
            result = FALSE;
        }
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

This code works and returns correct results.

How can this be implemented using `fork()` and `waitpid()` without the status variable (it won't work with `fork()` anyway...) and pipes? I tried to find solutions with different options for the last function (`waitpid()`), but a desired combination was not found.

Comment: I'm confused how this does work, but `volatile` shouldn't have any effect there. I can reproduce behavior with or without the `volatile`.

Comment: `char* argsToExec[2] = { args, NULL };` needs to be set *before* the call to `vfork()`.  Memory manipulations like that in the child process of a `vfork()` invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: ... until I add `-O`, then the behavior changes.

Comment: @aschepler, without <code>volatile</code>, as I understood, child does not change the status variable in the way for parent process to see changes

Comment: Read the man page for `vfork`. The child process is not allowed to change any variables at all, except `procHandle`.

Comment: @aschepler, yeah, I did. And because of this I want to use a classic fork(), but I cannot find a solution for sending a result of exec*() execution to a parent process without pipes... Or pipes are the only option in this case?

Comment: A pipe is probably the easiest option.

Comment: @aschepler, but there are still other variants?)

Comment: `vfork()` is never a good idea.

Comment: This version with `vfork` also will not always work as intended. `exec` can fail after this function has already returned true